# How do I borrow a method of a class without extending it?

Tags: javascript

Basically I want to use `First.showName` class' method in context of `Second` class, but have no idea how to access it.

```
 class First {
        constructor(){
            this.elem = document.createElement("br");
        }
        showName = function (){
            console.log('Name of the node:',this.elem.nodeName);
        }
    }

class Second  {
    constructor(){
        this.elem = document.createElement("div");
    }
    showName = First.showName.bind(this); // error!
    showName = First.prototype.showName.bind(this); // error!
    showName = First.__proto__.showName.bind(this); // error!
}

window.testObject = new Second();
testObject.showName();
```

Comment: `showName` is not declared with valid syntax.

Comment: why not inherit from First ?

Comment: I want to make it another branch of classes so to say, for another type of objects, just with some borrowed methods. It's not obligatory in my realisation, but I decided I might as well do it this way.

Comment: Then the best way may be a shared abstract base class from which both classes inherit.

Comment: @ConstantinGuidon because inheritance just for the sake of sharing code is not a good idea. Remember the "composition over inheritance" advice. In fact, with that in mind it should be better to have both `First` and `Second` both use a common thing for `showName`. Although that could be implemented as a mixin rather than composition.

Comment: maybe something like `First.prototype.showName.apply(this, ...arguments)` ?

Answer (score 2):

Let's put aside the `element` part for now and focus only on JavaScript.

Your First class has a method. But classes in JavaScript are just syntactic sugar over prototypes. So:

```
class First {
  showName() { console.log(this.name); }
}
```

is the same as:

```
function First() {
}

First.prototype.showName = function() { console.log(this.name); };
```

So, basically, we want to take that function from the prototype of the `class First`. There are several ways to do this.

---

An easy way would be to extend the *prototype* of the second class:

```js
class First {
  showName() { console.log(this.name); }
}
class Second {}
Second.prototype.showName = First.prototype.showName;

const node = new Second();
node.name = 'Second has a name now.';
node.showName();
```

---

Another way would be on instantiation:

```js
class First {
  showName() { console.log(this.name); }
}
class Second {
  constructor() {
    this.showName = First.prototype.showName;
  }
}

const node = new Second();
node.name = 'Second node.';
node.showName();
```

After that, it should be easy to adjust the *contents* of the function as you see fit.

---

**Edit:** after some comments on the question, here's also a gist of a composable way to do the same:

```js
const showName = function showName() { console.log(this.name); }

class First {}
class Second {}

First.prototype.showName = showName;
Second.prototype.showName = showName;

const node = new Second();
node.name = 'Second name.';
node.showName();
```

Comment: You don’t even need the `.bind(this)`.

Comment: So, second way is basically like what I've written but inside of the constructor?

Comment: @IgorCheglakov Yeah. For what it is worth, the first way is a tad more performant - you only adjust the prototype, and you do it once. The constructor way basically adds a method to every instance, on creation of that instance. So to spare a few cycles, the first way would be better.

Answer (score -1):

The method declaration is wrong, should be:

```
myMethod() {
}
```

Do it the right way and create a base class for common methods and properties and inherit any class which will share these properties from it:

```js
class Base {
  constructor(){
    this.name = "";
  }
  showName(){
        console.log('Name of the node:', this.name);
    }
}

class First extends Base {
    constructor(){
      super();
        this.elem = document.createElement("br");
        this.name = this.elem.nodeName;
    }
}

class Second extends Base  {
    constructor() {
          super();
        this.elem = document.createElement("div");
        super.name = this.elem.nodeName;
    }
}

window.testObject = new Second();
testObject.showName();
```

That's OOP as it's best and not XGH.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

Comment: You don’t need to and should not instantiate `First` (which may have a whole rats tail of stuff going on) just to get the method.

Comment: So in this exact realisation I can't evade creating a useless `br` element?

Comment: @deceze Yeah you're right, but my whole answer is not that bad. Anyway, I don't a good ideia to reference the first class property to the second class tho, that's nasty. OP should create a base class and inherit both class from it.

Comment: @IgorCheglakov ok, that's a problem, but your whole archtecture is bad, by refencing a method directly, where in OOP programing thats defined ? Being **possible** do it doens't means it is **right**.

Comment: @IgorCheglakov while I agree with some things here in this answer and have a slightly different opinion on others, I somewhat agree with the sentiment that your architecture might be improvable. This 'br' thing is really sticking out. If you describe more of the context and problem, perhaps in another question, there could be better ways to do this.

Comment: The parent method `Taker` creates an exemplar of wrapper object for a `<div>` element. It has two methods: `Taker.buildText(textContent, classList)` which creates a `span` element, with `this.textContent = textContent` and classes and appends itself to `div` and `Taker.buildField(defaultText, classList)`, that also adds css class with gray color, a `.textField` class and  makes the `defaultText` as a property of the `span`. I want to apply these methods to a class of  `<ol>` numbered list

Comment: @IgorCheglakov well, cards are on the table, pick the best which fits your scenario.